# Can you Identify the sql server name from sql backup file(.bak)?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I have a backup file from an SQL 2016 server and I need to identify which SQL server the file was created on. Is there a way to identify the original SQL server where the file originated at?  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You could run a `RESTORE HEADERONLY` on the backup file to read the contents and get the `ServerName` column.

For example:

```
CREATE DATABASE BLABLA
GO

backup database BLABLA
to disk = 'c:\temp\BLABLA.BAK'

RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'c:\temp\BLABLA.BAK'
```

Result:

[image]

With the servername column being the one you want for the backup(s) residing in the backup file.

[image]